# LuaLaTeX: Is it possible to create multiple log files/custom edit the log output

Tags: luatex, logging

I'm trying to typeset a book, and I'd like to print some messages in the log file (or somewhere else), in order to easily read them and correct my layout or the calculations beneath it.

Currently I use the `\typeout` command, but my message gets swallowed by all of the build stuff (and also by warnings, etc.)

Is it possible to achieve what I would gladly like, especially with LuaLaTex, which I'm using now?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's straighforward in Lua, e.g. `f = io.open(filename, "w")` and then `f:write(some_string)`.